# MSIX appPrinter-Extension on MS-Server

Tags: desktop-bridge, msix

I created an MSIX-App which uses the appPrinter Extension (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#make-your-application-appear-as-the-print-target-in-applications-that-support-printing), meaning a printer is registered after installation and visible in the printer list. As soon as a document is printed over the created printer, the application opens.

Works fine on Win10 and Win11. I now tried to install the MSIX-Package via the cmdlet (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2022-ps) on MS-Server2022.
The application is installed correctly and visible, unfortunately the printer is **not ** visible.

Any solutions, or is there a reason why the printer is not visible?

Best regards